# How can I only read one line of data from a TCPSocket in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, sockets, eventmachine

I'm using the following code to connect to a network service i'm writing (thats backed by EventMachine) and I'm having a bit of trouble getting into a situation allowing me to use one socket connection to execute multiple commands.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'socket'

opts = {
  :address => "0.0.0.0",
  :port => 2478
}

connection = TCPSocket.open opts[:address], opts[:port]

# Get ID
connection.print "ID something"
puts connection.read

# Status
connection.print "STATUS"
puts connection.read

# Close the connection
connection.close
```

Here's what my EventMachine server hander looks like...

```
module ConnectionHandler

  def receive_data data
    send_data "Some output #{data}"
  end
end
```

However, my first ruby script hangs when it executes `connection.read` as I presume its waiting for the connection to close so it knows its got all of the data? This is not what I want to happen.

My socket server will just take one command (on one line) and return one line of output.

Any ideas how I can do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the `connection.gets` method will return a line of data received if the server sends a response ending in a \n character. So I just added `\n` to the end of my `send_data` call and switch to using `puts connection.gets` and it worked great!

Comment: So you should delete that answer and upvote and accept the other one, because `puts` also adds a newline. This would only be fair.